# Divider disappears on expansion

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How do i get this output[image]

HI,Hello and the capital letters are the group Tittles and the small letters are the children

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to provide divider for the child of the expandable groups than only you will be able to achieve what you want.Because on expansion the divider of the child of the respective group will act as the divider between last child of that group and the next group.